# Apache 403 Access Denied since win 10 anniversary update

Tags: apache, windows-10

My windows 10 automagically updated to the anniversary version. Since then i can't make my projects in www, vhosts and aliases work. (before this update everything worked just fine...)
At the moment i get the access denied (http 403) error.
Does anyone have any idea what's happened/happening and/or how i can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.. are you using `wamp` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using wamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling & digging further, I've noticed that I could see files in the www folder, only not the files from the project I was working on. So I tried cloning the project again and that fixed it. Guess win 10 update broke some file permissions or something...